# Is storing users' passwords in FirebaseDatabase is a good idea?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am making an app, and in that app, users login and I am storing their information; however, I have noticed that I don't have a users' password information after they register. Is it a good idea to store users' password when they register through Firebase? And is there a point where I will need their passwords? I want to make sure before I proceed further. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do not do that.

Use the (awesome, amazing) Firebase authentication system.

Click right here:

[image]

**on the left**, to see all the users - click **"Authentication"**.

You never see / you cannot see their passwords.

You don't handle or touch the passwords at all.

In the Android or iOS app, you get the userid - and that's it.

**The answer by @PeterHaddad shows perfectly how to do that.**

That's the first and most basic step in any Firebase ios/droid app.

In your data you'll have a "table" called probably "userData/" and that's where you keep all data about the user.  (For example, you may store their address, real name, shoe size .. whatever is relevant in your app.)

Note - FBase is so amazing, your users can also connect with other methods (phone, etc).  For your reference in the future, that is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48692393/294884)

Comment: Firebase doesn't show users' password in the console. So I guess you are saying "Dont save passwords"?

Comment: That's totally correct, @YunusKulyyev.  (1) you the developer can NOT see the passwords.  (2) there is no WAY to see the passwords.  (3) you never NEED to see the passwords.  I hope, it makes sense!

Comment: Sure.   I added some more detail, and you might want to read the link at the end - and the other answer is good too!  :)  Enjoy @YunusKulyyev

Comment: @Fattie hey, i have a case for the user to change his password so how can i handle it if I don't save his password?

Comment: hi @OliverD - good news, they have a system for that and it is trivial.  indeed there are many questions on here "firebase, change password?" - or, ask a new question on SO!   there's a couple different ways to do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/42174864/294884

Comment: what about the case of no network? Wouldn't be better to save email + password in  DB through Room so user can still access app feature on offline mode?

Comment: if you're offline, you cannot login

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to store the password in the firebase database, after you authenticate the user using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` the email and other info will be stored in the authentication console. So you do not need the password in the database, all you need is the userid to connect auth with database.

```
FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String useruid=user.getUid();
```

Comment: hey, i have a case for the user to change his password so how can i handle it if I don't save his password?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39866086/change-password-with-firebase-for-android

Comment: @PeterHaddad hi peter, i have a quick question. i have react native app for users and a react web app for the admin, i am using firebase authentication to log the admin into the admin panel. i am also storing their uid in a admin collection. i kept reading some answers and they same firebase authentication allows any user authenticated to login, does this mean the user using their credentials can log into my admin panel?